# bash + how to avoid specific messages in the log file

Tags: linux, bash, redhat, log-files, shell-scripting

when I run the bash script on my Linux machine we get the following errors in my log ,

note - we set in the script:

```
exec > $log 2>&1 ,  (  in order to send all standard error/output to $log )
```

the errors messages:

```
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
```

in order to filter this errors messages we try to set in the bash script that:

```
export TERM=xterm
```

**but without help**

after digging we found that  happened in some case for example when we perform ssh to remote machine and runs commands on remote machine VIA ssh

in order to avoid that we set TERM=xterm  in the bash script as the following:

```
ssh user@$remote_machine "TERM=xterm  /tmp/script.sh"
```

but it’s very not elegant solution and because my script use a lot of ssh and curl command then it’s not practical solution to set this on each SSH or curl etc

**so my big question is**

how to filter the message – **tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified** ?

so we not get these ugly message in my **$log** file

Comment: Just run sed and delete all lines in the logfile that match the string, make this sed command the last line of your shell script.

Comment: I want to do it on the fly  not after log is completed

Comment: why (-1) on this excellent question - what is going on this site its craze

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe your output with "grep --invert-match "tput: No value for \$TERM and no -T specified".